# Learn JRuby or Ruby as a Java developer?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I've been thinking about learning Ruby/Rails to build RESTful APIs and was wondering what route I should go down in learning Ruby/Rails.

I am most versed and comfortable with Java, so I was wondering if I should learn the Ruby language completely or if I can get away with just using JRuby in Java? Would I still need to learn a significant amount of Ruby for using JRuby on Rails? (At which point I might as well just learn Ruby completely?)

Comment: Yep, can't do JRuby without knowing Ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JRuby is just a Ruby interpreter that happens to be built on top of the JVM. You'd still be learning similar amounts of Ruby either way. JRuby, because it runs on the JVM, is able to do interop with other JVM languages. So as a Java developer, you may find that somewhat useful.

Comment: I see thanks, any suggestions on resources for learning Ruby? Specifically any resources that cater to people who already know a language like C++ or Java, because I don't want to be bogged down in having inheritance, polymorphism, and etc explained to me again.

Comment: check the #ruby tag on SO It has listed quite a couple good starting points  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info